# CUDA 2.1 "error: unknown type name 'size_t'"

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, nvidia, nvcc, size-t

System: Ubuntu 11.10 x86_64
CUDA: v 2.1

When trying to make an example program like matrixMul I get an extensive amount of errors, most of which are "unknown type name 'size_t'." I've made sure to put /usr/local/cuda/bin in my PATH as well as /usr/local/cuda/lib in a .conf in /etc/ld.so.conf.d.

Any ideas why I'm getting these errors?

```
matrixMul$ make emu=1
In file included from /tmp/tmpxft_00004089_00000000-1_matrixMul.cudafe1.stub.c:5:0,
                 from matrixMul.cu:196:
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:192:0: warning: "__device_fun" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:215:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:194:0: warning: "__device_var" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:217:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:196:0: warning: "__tex_var" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:219:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:198:0: warning: "__cudaFatCubin" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:221:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:208:0: warning: "__ids" redefined [enabled by default]
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:223:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/builtin_types.h:43:0,
                 from /usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/cuda_runtime_api.h:54,
                 from /usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:80,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h:156:
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/driver_types.h:184:3: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
...
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/driver_types.h:274:3: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
In file included from /usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:80:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h:156:
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/cuda_runtime_api.h:102:46: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
...
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/cuda_runtime_api.h:105:118: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
In file included from /usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:80:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h:156:
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/cuda_runtime_api.h:110:48: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
In file included from /usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:80:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h:156:
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/cuda_runtime_api.h:120:59: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
...
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/cuda_runtime_api.h:121:110: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
In file included from /usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:80:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++config.h:156:
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/cuda_runtime_api.h:122:80: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
...
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/cuda_runtime_api.h:216:68: error: unknown type name ‘size_t’
In file included from /usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:226:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include/stddef.h:213:
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/common_functions.h:70:1: error: unknown type name ‘clock_t’
/usr/include/time.h:183:43: error: conflicting types for ‘clock’
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/common_functions.h:72:10: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘clock’ was here
../../common/inc/cutil_inline_runtime.h:41:49: warning: inline function ‘_Z23cutGetMaxGflopsDeviceIdv’ declared weak [-Wattributes]
../../common/inc/cutil_inline_runtime.h:41:43: warning: inline function ‘_Z23cutGetMaxGflopsDeviceIdv’ declared weak [-Wattributes]
In file included from /tmp/tmpxft_00004089_00000000-1_matrixMul.cudafe1.stub.c:4:0,
                 from matrixMul.cu:196:
/usr/include/time.h:183:34: error: conflicting types for ‘__cuda_clock’
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/common_functions.h:70:16: note: previous definition of ‘__cuda_clock’ was here
In file included from /tmp/tmpxft_00004089_00000000-1_matrixMul.cudafe1.stub.c:4:0,
                 from matrixMul.cu:196:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:193:30: error: static declaration of ‘__cuda_error_not_implememted’ follows non-static declaration
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/math_functions.h:864:78: note: previous declaration of ‘__cuda_error_not_implememted’ was here
In file included from /tmp/tmpxft_00004089_00000000-1_matrixMul.cudafe1.stub.c:5:0,
                 from matrixMul.cu:196:
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:185:13: error: redefinition of ‘__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil’
/usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/crt/host_runtime.h:185:13: note: previous definition of ‘__cudaUnregisterBinaryUtil’ was here
make: *** [obj/emurelease/matrixMul.cu.o] Error 255
```

Thanks!

Comment: /usr/include/time.h:183:34: error: conflicting types for ‘__cuda_clock’ /usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/common_functions.h:70:16: note: previous definition of ‘__cuda_clock’ was here  says that you are including some functions twice.. Are your versions of c and cuda compatible.. make sure that the header files needed for compilation are available.. e.g open the file /usr/local/cuda//bin/../include/driver_types.h:184:3 and see that you can find the header files that it it using and that they are in the path.. the command locate is very helpful in findin elusive headers

Comment: size_t is available inside <cstring> so maybe include that in header and see if that fixes some bugs atleast

Comment: You are using a *very old* CUDA toolkit with an unsupported compiler. Either get a newer CUDA version, or install gcc 4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrade CUDA!

CUDA 2.1 was released in 2008/9, you should upgrade (for example to [CUDA 4.2](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)). Officially Ubuntu 11.10 is not yet supported, I haven't tried it myself, the main issue is likely to be that you will have to install GCC 4.5.2. See the [Release Notes](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_Toolkit_Release_Notes.txt) for more information on supported versions.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you `#include <stddef.h>`

If this is a C++ program, try adding the line `using namespace std`.

The problem has nothing to do with "bin" or your $PATH; it has everything to do with which system headers and system definitions you're picking up at compile time.